# SharePoint + Microsoft Edge Chromium Issue with installing VSTO file

Tags: office-365, edge

We currently host **Clickonce installers (VSTO)** in **SharePoint Document Library** to distribute the **Word Addins** to users. Until now most of them used **Internet Explorer** and when clicking on **VSTO** file, it installs the word addin directly from SharePoint and it also helps in releasing the future addin updates.

**Problem**: We are currently migrating to Microsoft Edge Chromium browser. When we click on the VSTO file, it downloads locally and installation fails.

**Additional Information**: We tried hosting the VSTO installer in IIS directly and tested with a simple HTML page with the link to the VSTO file: It nicely installs the addin using MSEdge Chromium browser. We narrowed down that it is the SharePoint+MSEdge issue.

Has anyone faced this issue, it will be great if you could help.

We are currently using **SharePoint 2013** with **MSOffice Client - Word 365**

Microsoft Edge Version: **86.0.622.69 (Official build) (64-bit)**

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by installing Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime.  Subsequently, VSTO packages installed as expected through Edge\IE.